# socket server returns tcp error [RST, ACK] for somme requests

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, tcp

I developed a server with c on linux using socket.

The server is runnig without problem. If I made a request from my web browser to the server, The server respond to the request without problem.

But I remarked in the capture traffic (using wireshark) that my server reurns some times (rarely) a tcp error [RST, ACK].

here after the tcp error packet as shown in the wireshark

[image: TCP error capture]

The 192.168.1.211 is the address of my server

I checked the "follow tcp stream", I found that it contains 2 requests (from the web browser). I think it should contains only one request in a given socket. Am I right?

Here after the follow tcp stream:

[image: follow tcp stream]

I do not know if this is a normal error and could happen in the TCP stack? or it's a problem related to my code?

**Code:**

```
static void http_cr_new_client(int client, bool service_available)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int8_t auth_status = 0;

    fp = fdopen(client, "r+");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        if (!strncasecmp(buffer, "Authorization: Digest ", strlen("Authorization: Digest "))) {
            char *username = conf.cpe_userid;
            char *password = conf.cpe_passwd;

            if (!username || !password) {
                // if we dont have username or password configured proceed with connecting to ACS
                service_available = false;
                goto http_end;
            }

            if (http_digest_auth_check("GET", "/", buffer + strlen("Authorization: Digest "), REALM, username, password, 300) == MHD_YES)
                auth_status = 1;
            else
                auth_status = 0;
        }

        if (buffer[0] == '\r' || buffer[0] == '\n') {
            /* end of http request (empty line) */
            goto http_end;
        }
    }
    if(!service_available) {
        goto http_end;
    }

http_error:
        /* here we are because of an error, e.g. timeout */
    goto http_done;

http_end:
    if (!service_available) {
        MY_LOG (INFO,"Receive Connection Request: Return 503 Service Unavailable");
        fputs("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable\r\n", fp);
        fputs("Connection: close\r\n", fp);
    } else if (auth_status) {
        MY_LOG (INFO,"Receive Connection Request: success authentication");
        fputs("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n", fp);
        fputs("Content-Length: 0\r\n", fp);
        http_success_cr();
    } else {
        MY_LOG (INFO,"Receive Connection Request: Return 401 Unauthorized");
        fputs("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n", fp);
        fputs("Connection: close\r\n", fp);
        http_digest_auth_fail_response(fp, "GET", "/", REALM, OPAQUE);
        fputs("\r\n", fp);
    }
    fputs("\r\n", fp);
http_done:
    fclose(fp);
    close(client);
}

void http_server_init(void)
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    static int cr_request = 0;
    static time_t restrict_start_time = 0;
    time_t current_time;
    bool service_available;

    for(;;) {
        //Create socket
        socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
        if (socket_desc == -1)
        {
            MY_LOG (ERROR,"Could not open server socket for Connection Requests");
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }

        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons(conf.connection_request_port);

        /* enable SO_REUSEADDR */
        int reusaddr = 1;
        if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reusaddr, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
            MY_LOG (WARNING,"setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
        }

        //Bind
        if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            //print the error message
            MY_LOG (ERROR,"Could not bind server socket for Connection Requests");
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    MY_LOG (INFO,"Connection Request server initiated");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        current_time = time(NULL);
        service_available = true;
        if ((restrict_start_time==0) ||
            ((current_time-restrict_start_time) > CONNECTION_REQUEST_RESTRICT_PERIOD))
        {
            restrict_start_time = current_time;
            cr_request  = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cr_request++;
            if (cr_request > 70)
            {
                restrict_start_time = current_time;
                service_available = false;
            }
        }
        http_cr_new_client(client_sock, service_available);
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        MY_LOG(ERROR,"Could not accept connections for Connection Requests!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Note: I launch the server in the main with `pthread_create()`

Comment: fclose(fp); close(client); where fp is opened client descriptor... aren't you trying to write to closed connection?

Comment: @0d0a `fclose(fp); close(client); ` are put at the end of the function after read/write of the socket. So I think there is no problem with that

Comment: The call to `close()` will fail. From `man fdopen`: `The file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream created by fdopen() is closed.` And if doesn't fail this means it randomly `close()`ed another socket descriptor, propably one belonging to another thread. In any case you might like to add error checking also for calling `close()`.

Comment: `[RST, ACK]` generally means one of two things: (1) trying to connect to a port that's nobody is listening to, and (2) sending data to a closed connection, i.e. one where you're already sent a `[FIN]`.  In this instance it seems most likely that cause (2) is the case in point.  Also, it'd help to see what other traffic is passing on port 35897.  You can use a Wireshark filter expression to limit teh displayed data to just that session.  That would provide some context as to what's happened.  Seeing a single random `[RST, ACK]` doesn't tell a great deal about how we got there.

Comment: @dgnuff You can't send data after a FIN. It's impossible. The local TCP won't let you. Writing to a closed connection means one that has already been closed *by the peer,* for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting to process only a single request in your code. The HTTP protocol added persistent connections in version 1.1, which allow the same TCP socket to be reused for more than 1 request.

With persistent connections, the client (your browser) would send the "Connection: keep-alive" header to indicate that it supports persistent connections (which your browser does). The server can then reply with the same, or use "Connection: close" to indicate that it does not support persistent connections, so the client should close the current socket and open a new one for subsequent requests.

In your case, the browser opens a socket connection, sends a request and tells you that it support persistent connections. Your server then sends a response and closes the connection. The browser tries to send a second request over the same connection and fails, resulting in the error you see.

You can either modify your code to keep the socket open and handle multiple requests, or add "Connection: close" to tell the client that you do not support persistent connections.